# tkinter - How to stop frame changing size when widget is added?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, frames

In the Page frame, I've weighted two frames inside innerFrame so that they each take up half of the screen, however, when I add a widget to one of these frames, I've used a listbox as an example as it is large, one of the frames now takes up more than the other. How do I make it so that the frames don't change size when a widget is added and each remain half the size of the window?

[image: Without Listbox]

[image: With Listbox]

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Program(tk.Tk):        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default = "")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Page, Other):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(Page)

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class Page(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):


        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        innerFrame = tk.Frame(self, bg="red")
        innerFrame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c", relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)


        innerFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        innerFrame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        innerFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #First Half
        frameOne = tk.Frame(innerFrame, bg="pink")
        frameOne.grid(row=0, sticky="NSWE")

        #Second Half
        frameTwo = tk.Frame(innerFrame, bg="green")
        frameTwo.grid(row=1, sticky="NSWE")

        lb = tk.Listbox(frameTwo)
        lb.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


class Other(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)



app = Program()
app.state('zoomed')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not sure you should be mixing pack, place and grid on the same widgets. On `innerFrame` you place it first, then use grid configuration. I have usually just used grid, but maybe someone with experience in using place and pack  can elaborate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grid accepts the parameter `uniform`, which takes an arbitrary value. All rows (or all columns) with the same value are considered to be part of a "uniform group". This forces the rows (or columns) to be a uniform size in proportion to their weight.

If you have two rows in a frame, both rows have an identical weight, and both belong to the same uniform group, they will each take up exactly 50% of the available space.

In your case you can do this:

```
innerFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="x")
innerFrame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="x")
```

(again, the "x" is arbitrary; it can be any value as long as it's the same value for both rows)

The official documentation for tk (upon which tkinter is built) describes it like this (see http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/grid.htm#M24)

> The -uniform option, when a non-empty value is supplied, places the row in a uniform group with other rows that have the same value for -uniform. The space for rows belonging to a uniform group is allocated so that their sizes are always in strict proportion to their -weight values.

...

> When multiple rows or columns belong to a uniform group, the space allocated to them is always in proportion to their weights. (A weight of zero is considered to be 1.) In other words, a row or column configured with -weight 1 -uniform a will have exactly the same size as any other row or column configured with -weight 1 -uniform a. A row or column configured with -weight 2 -uniform b will be exactly twice as large as one that is configured with -weight 1 -uniform b.

---

Note: the `uniform` option doesn't show up in the tkinter documentation, but it is a perfectly valid option. It has been a part of tk (upon which tkinter is built) for many, many years.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `max-size`, `min-sixe` to the frame:

```
master = tk()
master.minsize(width=777, height=777)
master.maxsize(width=777, height=777)
```